# Can figures be copied from the pdf?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

using the variable clipboard in g1ant I can copy the store or copy the content of pdf but I have noticed it does not copy the images from the document. Is there any way from which I can copy the images?

```
keyboard ⋘ALT⋙⋘DOWN⋙⋘4⋙
keyboard ⋘CTRL+A⋙⋘CTRL+C⋙
♥copy = ♥clipboard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store images in variables of text structure that is why they are not present in the special variable `♥clipboard` but you can use the `CTRL+V` shortcut instead. Here's an example:

```
selenium.open chrome url g1ant.com
keyboard ⋘ctrl+a⋙⋘ctrl+c⋙
word.open
window ✱Word✱
keyboard ⋘Ctrl+V⋙
```